# Working with Root objects for a ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I want to plot a parametric plot for 2 variables `e11` and `s11` which depend on `0<=c<=1`. Here `e11` is a `Root` object obtained as below:

```
Xt = 1/(37617.37590264494` - 591.4506750110327` c - 
    50.6866378885597` c^2 + 
    1.` c^3) (-3137.4640264225636` - 
     136154.31329790497` e11 Sqrt[1 + 2 e11] - 
     0.008214030015896925` c^5 e11 Sqrt[1 + 2 e11] + 
     0.000042533535676195276` c^6 e11 Sqrt[1 + 2 e11] + 
     c (2203.389087814458` - 
        3943.7346350900393` e11 Sqrt[1 + 2 e11]) + 
     c^4 (0.057262350184919764` + 
        0.12016460915359387` e11 Sqrt[1 + 2 e11]) + 
     c^3 (-2.9858406572838176` + 
        9.762007101438348` e11 Sqrt[1 + 2 e11]) + 
     c^2 (-29.64035443698749` + 
        51.23107199024322` e11 Sqrt[1 + 2 e11]));

s = Solve[Xt == 0 && 0 <= c <= 1, e11, Reals]

s11 = (71 (1 - c) + 53.5 c) e11;
```

How can I manipulate `e11` so that I can use it in `ParametricPlot[{e11, s11}, {c, 0, 1}]`?

Any pointers are much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't given us the definition of `s11`; however, try `ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{e11 /. s[[1]], s11}], {c, 0, 1}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you for your comment. I have updated s11. I have also tried your suggestion, but it just gives me an empty plot. I am not sure what to make of it.

Comment: Adjust Bob's suggestion to apply the solution to both expressions, `e11` and `s11`, since both depend on the solution for `e11`: `ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{e11, s11} /. s[[1]]], {c, 0, 1}]` -- maybe add `AspectRatio -> 1` to `ParametricPlot[]`.  See the docs for `Solve[]`, the tutorial [Manipulating Equations and Inequalities](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ManipulatingEquationsAndInequalities.html), and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18706#18706 for more about using the solutions produced by `Solve[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) is an exact solver, it should generally be given exact numbers (use [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html))

```
Xt = 1/(37617.37590264494` - 591.4506750110327` c - 50.6866378885597` c^2 + 
       1.` c^3) (-3137.4640264225636` - 
      136154.31329790497` e11 Sqrt[1 + 2 e11] - 
      0.008214030015896925` c^5 e11 Sqrt[1 + 2 e11] + 
      0.000042533535676195276` c^6 e11 Sqrt[1 + 2 e11] + 
      c (2203.389087814458` - 3943.7346350900393` e11 Sqrt[1 + 2 e11]) + 
      c^4 (0.057262350184919764` + 0.12016460915359387` e11 Sqrt[1 + 2 e11]) +
       c^3 (-2.9858406572838176` + 9.762007101438348` e11 Sqrt[1 + 2 e11]) + 
      c^2 (-29.64035443698749` + 51.23107199024322` e11 Sqrt[1 + 2 e11])) //
   Rationalize[#, 0] &;

s = Solve[Xt == 0 && 0 <= c <= 1, e11, Reals];

s11 = (71 (1 - c) + 53.5 c) e11;

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{e11, s11} /. s[[1]]], {c, 0, 1},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"e11", "s11"}),
 ColorFunction -> Function[{e11, s11, c}, ColorData["Rainbow"][c]],
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   BarLegend["Rainbow",
    LegendLabel -> Style[c, 14]],
   {.8, .6}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although there's an approved answer, I decided to fix two errors in my answer. There are multiple solutions from Solve, and I overlooked the requirement to plot e11 vs s11.

Pick out the first solution and flatten to get rid of nested lists.

```
s = Flatten[e11 /. First@Solve[Xt == 0 && 0 <= c <= 1, e11, Reals]];
s11 = (71 (1 - c) + 53.5 c) s;
```

Now the result can be plotted:

```
ParametricPlot[{s, s11}, {c, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]